# Error on integrating SFML and wxWidget

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets, sfml

I would like to create an apps using SFML and wxWidget. Because it's kind of level editor for a game so I need the rendering part of SFML and integrate it with native button

I was able to compile the example of SFML, and also I was able to compile the example of wxWidget. But after I follow the tutorial in this link: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-wxwidgets.php , my IDE give me these errors.

```
"sf::RenderWindow::OnCreate()", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow()", referenced from:
   wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long)in wxSFMLCanvas.o
  wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long)in wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()", referenced from:
  wxSFMLCanvas::~wxSFMLCanvas()in wxSFMLCanvas.o
  wxSFMLCanvas::~wxSFMLCanvas()in wxSFMLCanvas.o
  wxSFMLCanvas::~wxSFMLCanvas()in wxSFMLCanvas.o
  wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long)in wxSFMLCanvas.o
  wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long)in wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::Window::Create(void*, sf::WindowSettings const&)", referenced from:
  wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long)in wxSFMLCanvas.o
  wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long)in wxSFMLCanvas.o

 "non-virtual thunk to sf::RenderWindow::GetHeight() const", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"non-virtual thunk to sf::RenderWindow::GetWidth() const", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::RenderWindow::GetHeight() const", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"typeinfo for sf::RenderWindow", referenced from:
  typeinfo for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::RenderWindow::Activate(bool)", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::RenderWindow::GetWidth() const", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::Window::Display()", referenced from:
  wxSFMLCanvas::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)       in wxSFMLCanvas.o

"non-virtual thunk to sf::RenderWindow::Activate(bool)", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::Window::OnEvent(sf::Event const&)", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o

"sf::RenderTarget::Draw(sf::Drawable const&)", referenced from:
  vtable for wxSFMLCanvasin wxSFMLCanvas.o
```

I have no any idea what those errors means. Do you have any experience about it?

Regards

p.s: I uve SFML ver. 1.6 and OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately I deleted my framework folder, after I restore it the errors gone